# Generics wildcards again.

Tags: java, generics

I got the following exception trying to introduce some generics in an interface (real code reduced to a general example):

`Type mismatch: cannot convert from capture#1-of ? extends Interface2<:? extends Interface1> to Interface2<:Interface1>`

The call that is failing is:

```
Interface2<Interface1> interface2Instance = interface1Instance.getInterface2ImplementorClass().newInstance();
```

and these are the interface definitions:

```
public interface Interface1{
  Class<? extends Interface2<? extends Interface1>> getInterface2ImplementorClass();
}

public interface Interface2<T extends Interface1> {
  public Object execute(T first, OtherClass1 second, OtherClass2 third,
        OtherClass3 baseTimeFormat) throws ChartScriptException;
}
```

I can change the failing line to:

```
Interface2<**? extends** Interface1> interface2Instance = interface1Instance.getInterface2ImplementorClass().newInstance();
```

But then I get the exception when I want to call

```
interface2Instance.execute(interface1Instance, second, third, forth);
```

I get the compiler error:

`The method execute(capture#3-of ? extends Interface1, OtherClass1, OtherClass2, OtherClass3) in the type Interface2<:capture#3-of ? extends Interface1> is not applicable for the arguments (Interface1, OtherClass1, OtherClass2, OtherClass3)`

I can't  find a way out of this confusion, what do I wrong and where can I look up the rule I'm breaking?

Comment: Your generic class names make this rather hard to parse.  In the future, I recommend fruit and vegetable names.

Answer (score 1):

Think of it this way: imagine `Interface2` was `List` and `Interface1` was `Number`.  The way you're calling the code, `newInstance()` *could* return a `List<Integer>` (since `Integer` extends `Number`) but assigning a `List<Integer>` to a `List<Number>` is invalid.  Here's why:

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Number> nums = ints; //if this was possible
nums.add(2.0);
Integer first = ints.get(0); //then this would fail
```

The technical term for this is *covariance*, and you can read more about it on [Angelika Langer's Generics FAQ](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/ParameterizedTypes.html#FAQ102).  In short, generic types are not covariant.

I'm not sure I can suggest a fix given your lack of concrete details.  You could have `getInterface2ImplementorClass()` return a `Class<? extends Interface2<Interface1>>` instead of a `Class<? extends Interface2<? extends Interface1>>`.

Comment: About your suggestion, that wasn't working, as I couldn't return a Interface2 implementor for an implementation of an Interface1